# Wait for event handlers to complete before continuing

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, user-controls

Let's say I have a user control named A that does the following:

```
Page_Load:
    List<object> myList = PrepareList();
    ListPrepared(this, new AArgs(myList)); // Event that lets subscribers modify the list.
    OperateOnAndDisplayList(myList);
```

An instance of A is held in a page that subscribes to the ListPrepared event and modifies the list that's created.  I want the page's handler to finish before I operate on and display the list, obviously, since it's modifying the list for completeness.  How would I go about implementing this?  (Or is this a horrible idea, since it exposes the list and thus requires outside elements to have knowledge of the list in order to modify it?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Events are raised synchronously.  This means that all subscribers to the event will execute their code before the `OperateOnAndDisplayList` method is called.  This also means that if `myList` is modified by any of the event subscribers, the modification will be visible to the event publisher as well.  If this isn't what you want, you should create a copy of the list before raising the event, and only send the copy with the event's `EventArgs`.

Comment: Oh.  I thought they were asynchronous.  Well, that makes this question rather silly.

Comment: Haha, I originally thought they were async too when I first started using them.  Events are just a fancy type of delegate, a `MulticastDelegate`... all that means is that you can have a list of delegates to handle the event rather than just a single delegate.

Comment: Any delegate is a Multicast delegate. There are 3 differences between them: 1. Events can be invoked only from the class that created them. 2. Events work only with "+=" and "-=" operators but not with "=". 3. Events can be interface members and delegates can't.

Comment: Events are synchronous, but the event handler can do async operations and not wait for their completion.

Comment: @AmiramKorach +1, those are good points about the difference between events and a simple MulticastDelegate

Comment: Actually the .NET team started with a delegate and a Multicast delegate but now they are the same. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/02/05/68415.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If the event handler is returning when all its code is done, that you don't have to worry about it. Events are just a way of invoking methods. It is not related directly to async operations.